# Redirect to a subfolder using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have searched all the similar topics in the forum and nothing helped me. Here is what I am looking for:
I have a site having a login url as

```
site.com/folder1/php/login.php
```

Now I want to hide the "php" folder name from url, also remove .php extension so that it will look like

```
site.com/folder1/login
```

Also the folder name "folder1" may vary, but the folder name "php" remains the same in all urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /folder1/php/$2.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Modified the last line to be `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ folder1/php/$2.php [NC,L]` and it worked. but the folder1 may vary, so I had to put $1 there. so finally it is `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/php/$2.php [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

This should be working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+php/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^php/)^(.*)$ /php/$1 [L,NC]
```